# Buscador de en RecyclerView Arreglo non-static Arreglo Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Estoy haciendo un Buscador en `RecyclerView` Tengo bien mi adaptador y las clases pero cuando lo compilo me dice que el arreglo no es estático. Este arreglo se llena por medio de una consulta. La idea es que por medio de un text se pueda filtrar el `RecyclerView` he estado mirando varios vídeos pero todos tienen un arreglo estático pero este es dinámico. Necesito que uds me den una luz exactamente en donde tengo que corregir el código.

El método que estoy buscando es Buscar Este es mi activity:

```
package com.appeatbox;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public class List_RecyclerView extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etBuscador;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Players> itemList;

    String EmpSele;
    String NomSele;
    String TipSeleccion;

    int tipo_emp;
    String Sele;
    String url;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_recyclerview);
        loadEmpresas();
        etBuscador =findViewById(R.id.etBuscador);
        etBuscador.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                filtrar(s.toString());
            }
        });
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager( this));
        itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this,1);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        loadEmpresas();
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(List_RecyclerView.this, itemList);
        adapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EmpSele =  ""+itemList.get(recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getId();
                NomSele  =  ""+itemList.get(recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getNombre();
                // AlertDialog.Builder alertax = new AlertDialog.Builder(List_RecyclerView.this);
                // alertax.setMessage("Entre al click menu " + EmpSele).setNegativeButton("Continuar", null).create().show();
                Aplicacion app=(Aplicacion) getApplicationContext();
                app.setTipoSele(EmpSele.toString());
                Intent i = new Intent(List_RecyclerView.this, Pedidos.class);
                i.putExtra("EmpSele",EmpSele);
                i.putExtra("NomSele",NomSele);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void loadEmpresas(){
        Bundle extras =getIntent().getExtras();
        tipo_emp =  Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("Op"));
        Sele =  extras.getString("UsSele");
        TipSeleccion = extras.getString("TipSeleccion");

        TextView mSele = findViewById(R.id.MnuSele);
        mSele.setText(TipSeleccion);
        // final RequestParams parametros = new RequestParams();
        url = "https://leer_empresa_estadods.php?tipo="+ tipo_emp;
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                            AlertDialog.Builder alertax = new AlertDialog.Builder(List_RecyclerView.this);
                            alertax.setMessage( Sele + "\n"+ "Te ofrecemos: " +  array.length() + " Establecimiento(s)").setNegativeButton("Continuar", null).create().show();
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                                 JSONObject Item = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                itemList.add(new Players(
                                        Item.getInt("id"),
                                        Item.getString("nit"),
                                        Item.getString("nombre"),
                                        Item.getString("direccion"),
                                        Item.getString("photo")
                               ) );
                            }
                            Adapter adapter = new Adapter(List_RecyclerView.this, itemList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertax = new AlertDialog.Builder(List_RecyclerView.this);
                        alertax.setMessage("Tengo:" + error).setNegativeButton("Reintentar", null).create().show();
                    }
                });
        Volley.newRequestQueue( this).add(stringRequest);
    }

    public void filtrar(String texto){
        ArrayList<Players> filtrarlista = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Players players : itemList) {
            if (players.getNombre().toLowerCase().contains(texto.toLowerCase())) {
                filtrarlista.add(players);
            }
        }
        Adapter.Buscar(filtrarlista);<----**Aqui es donde me sale el error**
    }
}
```

Este es mi adaptador:

```
package com.appeatbox;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder>
            implements View.OnClickListener{
     Context mCtx;
     List<Players> itemList;
    private View.OnClickListener listener;
    RatingBar ratingBar;

    public Adapter(Context mCtx, List<Players> itemList){
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.itemList = itemList;
    }

    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout,  null);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);

    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position){
        Players item = itemList.get(position);
        Glide.with(mCtx)
                .load(item.getPhoto())
                .into(holder.imageView);
        holder.textView.setText(item.getNombre());
        holder.viewID.setText(""+item.getId());
        holder.view.setText(item.getDireccion());
        holder.textView.setText(itemList.get(position).getNombre());
    }

    public int getItemCount() { return itemList.size(); }

    public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
        this.listener=listener;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (listener!=null){
            listener.onClick(view);
        }
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView,view, viewID ;
        ImageView imageView;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemList){
            super(itemList);
            textView=itemList.findViewById(R.id.textName);
            view =itemList.findViewById(R.id.textDir);
            imageView = itemList.findViewById(R.id.imgEmpresa);
            viewID= itemList.findViewById(R.id.txtid);
            ratingBar=itemList.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        }
    }

***Aqui tengo el Buscar---->**    public void Buscar(ArrayList<Players> filtroUsuarios){
        this.itemList = filtroUsuarios;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Este es la clase donde identifico los valores de mi arreglo:

```
package com.appeatbox;
public class Players {
     int id;
     String nit;
     String nombre;
     String direccion;
     String photo;

    public Players(int id, String nit, String nombre, String direccion, String photo) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nit = nit;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id ){
        this.id =id;
    }
    public String getNit() {
        return nit;
    }
    public void setNit(String nit){
        this.nit = nit;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }
    public void setDireccion(String direccion){
        this.direccion= direccion;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }
    public void setPhoto(String photo){
        this.photo = photo;
    }
}
```

Comment: El error se debe porque el método `Buscar` no es estático, sino de instancia. Tienes dos soluciones. La primera es cambiar el método buscar como estático y la segunda es creando una instancia de tipo `Adapter` para lograr usar el método buscar.

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta que solo creas tu adapter luego de hacer tu llamada al server.
Lo que puedes intentar es tener un atributo de tipo `Adapter` en tu activity y luego de hacer el filtro llamar recién a tu método `buscar`.

```
public class List_RecyclerView extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText etBuscador;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<Players> itemList;
Adapter adapter; // Referencia a tu adapter

String EmpSele;
String NomSele;
String TipSeleccion;

int tipo_emp;
String Sele;
String url;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_recyclerview);
    itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new Adapter(List_RecyclerView.this, itemList);// Iniciar tu variable adapter y asignarle una lista vacía, dado que de momento no tienes items.
    loadEmpresas();
    etBuscador =findViewById(R.id.etBuscador);
    etBuscador.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            filtrar(s.toString());
        }
    });
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager( this));

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(this,1);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); //Dado que el adapter ya esta inicializado ya podemos asignarlo a nuestro RecyclerView 
    loadEmpresas();

    adapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EmpSele =  ""+itemList.get(recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getId();
            NomSele  =  ""+itemList.get(recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v)).getNombre();
            // AlertDialog.Builder alertax = new AlertDialog.Builder(List_RecyclerView.this);
            // alertax.setMessage("Entre al click menu " + EmpSele).setNegativeButton("Continuar", null).create().show();
            Aplicacion app=(Aplicacion) getApplicationContext();
            app.setTipoSele(EmpSele.toString());
            Intent i = new Intent(List_RecyclerView.this, Pedidos.class);
            i.putExtra("EmpSele",EmpSele);
            i.putExtra("NomSele",NomSele);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void loadEmpresas(){
    Bundle extras =getIntent().getExtras();
    tipo_emp =  Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("Op"));
    Sele =  extras.getString("UsSele");
    TipSeleccion = extras.getString("TipSeleccion");

    TextView mSele = findViewById(R.id.MnuSele);
    mSele.setText(TipSeleccion);
    // final RequestParams parametros = new RequestParams();
    url = "https://leer_empresa_estadods.php?tipo="+ tipo_emp;
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                        AlertDialog.Builder alertax = new AlertDialog.Builder(List_RecyclerView.this);
                        alertax.setMessage( Sele + "\n"+ "Te ofrecemos: " +  array.length() + " Establecimiento(s)").setNegativeButton("Continuar", null).create().show();
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                             JSONObject Item = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            itemList.add(new Players(
                                    Item.getInt("id"),
                                    Item.getString("nit"),
                                    Item.getString("nombre"),
                                    Item.getString("direccion"),
                                    Item.getString("photo")
                           ) );
                        }
                        adapter.Buscar(itemList);//Refrescamos nuestro adapter no los items

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertax = new AlertDialog.Builder(List_RecyclerView.this);
                    alertax.setMessage("Tengo:" + error).setNegativeButton("Reintentar", null).create().show();
                }
            });
    Volley.newRequestQueue( this).add(stringRequest);
}

public void filtrar(String texto){
    ArrayList<Players> filtrarlista = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Players players : itemList) {
        if (players.getNombre().toLowerCase().contains(texto.toLowerCase())) {
            filtrarlista.add(players);
        }
    }
    adapter.Buscar(filtrarlista);// Refrescamos con los items filtrados
}
```

}

Por último, recomendaría cambiar el nombre de tu método `Buscar` por un nombre que determine que es lo que esta haciendo como `setList` o `agregarElementos` para que tu código sea más entendible.

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: Hola rguzman todavia me sigue mostrando que no estatica